# Choice "goto was unexpected at this time"

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, cmd, goto

And thank you all before you even answer. So this is my first question in Stackoverflow.com i keep getting an error message saying "goto was unexpected at this time" i've searched for solution but i cant find anything. So if you know what im doing wrong tell me please :) im quite new to batch... im sorry if im doing really noobish mistake but i just cant tell whats wrong.

```
@echo off



:type
cls
echo %msg1%
echo %order%

choice /C abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz12 /n


if %errorlevel% == 28 goto save 
if %errorlevel% == 27 goto varsave 
if %errorlevel% == 26 goto set2 
if %errorlevel% == 25 goto set2
if %errorlevel% == 24 goto set2 
if %errorlevel% == 23 goto set2 
if %errorlevel% == 22 goto set2 
if %errorlevel% == 21 goto set2 
if %errorlevel% == 20 goto set2 
if %errorlevel% == 19 goto set2 
if %errorlevel% == 18 goto set2 
if %errorlevel% == 17 goto set2 
if %errorlevel% == 16 goto set2 
if %errorlevel% == 15 goto set2 
if %errorlevel% == 14 goto set2 
if %errorlevel% == 13 goto set2 
if %errorlevel% == 12 goto set2 
if %errorlevel% == 11 goto set2 
if %errorlevel% == 10 goto set2 
if %errorlevel% == 9 goto set 
if %errorlevel% == 8 goto set 
if %errorlevel% == 7 goto set 
if %errorlevel% == 6 goto set 
if %errorlevel% == 5 goto set
if %errorlevel% == 4 goto set 
if %errorlevel% == 3 goto set 
if %errorlevel% == 2 goto set 
if %errorlevel% == 1 goto set
```

Comment: your problem may not be a mistake rather a word choice because SET is also a command and since capital letters are ignored in command prompt it thinks you are trying to set a variable. so try changing SET to a different string also in order to use the goto command you need a matching location ie :a   goto a will create a Loop.

Comment: The code you posted should not give your stated error message, and the code works fine for me when I add some labels.

Comment: @CS_STEM - There is no restriction on using `:set` as a label. `GOTO SET` works just fine. The batch processor does not get confused with the SET command.

Comment: goto is generally considered harmful.  47 consecutive gotos definitely fall into the category of doing harm.

Comment: @StevenWestbrook I think goto would only be harmful if it is an infinite loop, however in this case the goto command is not called until an if statement is true.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get `goto was unexpected` is an empty %errorlevel% variable. That should never happen. Are you sure, that you didn't set it manually somewhere in your code (something like `set errorlevel=`?

As others stated already, your construct with `if %errorlevel% == xx` should work fine. But you can dramatically shorten your code, because `if errorlevel xx` really means: "If errorlevel is xx **or greater**" (not like `if %errorlevel% == xx`, wich does a string comparison):

```
@echo off
:type 
cls 
echo %msg1% echo %order%

choice /C abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz12 /n

if errorlevel 28 goto save
if errorlevel 27 goto varsave
if errorlevel 10 goto set2
if errorlevel 1 goto set
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the `%`s around `ERRORLEVEL`.  And remove the `==`s.

Comment: But `==` runs a string comparison.

Comment: it works the way it is. I know this because I compared it to my own code that works fine.

Comment: == does do a string comparison but %ERRORLEVEL% is determined by the user mainly from a key press in which case the %ERRORLEVEL% = what ever key the user pressed and as long as their is a matching comparison string it will return true other wise it does nothing.